# Ways to execute /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking

I am using tinycore Linux which does not have networkmanager.

It is my understanding that networkmanager is what runs /etc/network/interfaces

Is there some other way to execute the network setup that is in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: AFAIK the network setup defined by the /etc/network/interfaces file is managed by the older `networking` service, and is separate from the newer `NetworkManager` service (which has its own configuration files). I'm not familiar with tinycore, but t is usually the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands that are used to bring up / take down the interfaces defined in /etc/network/interfaces - try `man ifup`

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/network/interfaces` is the location for system network connections on Debian and derivatives. It is read by the commands in the [`ifupdown` package](https://packages.debian.org/ifupdown): `ifup` and `ifdown`. The [`interfaces` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) explains the basics of the file and the [Debian manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_basic_network_configuration_with_ifupdown_legacy) explains in more details. If you've configured an interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, run the `ifup` command to bring it up, e.g. `ifup eth0`.

NetworkManager does not process `/etc/network/interfaces`. Modern versions actually read it, but only to avoid touching the interfaces listed there.

Tiny Core Linux does not normally use `/etc/network/interfaces`. As far as I know (I'm not a Core user) you're supposed to run `ifconfig` or a DHCP client directly from the startup scripts (the installer does it for you). If you've installed ifupdown (on the dCore version?), then `ifup` is the command you're looking for, but otherwise `/etc/network/interfaces` isn't used.